# Simplified efficient string comparison minus punctuation, whitespace and case?

Tags: php, regex

I'm researching the most-efficient way to compare two strings regardless of whitespace, case or punctuation.

So that something like "hello there"  would == "HELLOthere!"

I am aware I can probably strip non-alphanumeric characters before a manual comparison, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant and efficient way to do this in PHP?  It would also be nice if it's character-set independent.

Comment: Normalise (e.g. strip punctuation and diacritics, fold to lowercase) and then compare is the only approach I can think of.

Comment: This sounds like something you'd want to use RegEx for

Comment: It would depend if you are comparing to the same thing lots of times, or just comparing arbitrary strings using those rules.  Compiling a different regular expression for every comparison would be less efficient.

Comment: "simplified" and "efficient" rarely go together. The more simple something is, the complicated it should be to handle any possible case. The more efficient something is, usually it is shorter, takes shortcuts and requires more work for formatting the initial input (think command line vs gui). Your best best honestly though would be like IMSoP is saying, normalize your strings on both sides of the comparison and then compare.

Comment: Given those recommendations... how would you do this if you were to write a function that compared two strings as parameters?  I know there are several ways to strip the strings - wondering what's most memory/speed efficient?  

i.e.

function simple_compare(string1,string2) 

returning 1 if equal, 0 if not equal.

Comment: here' what I came up with - wondering if anyone would have a better idea:

`function simple_compare(str1,str2) {

 $x=strtolower(ereg_replace("[^[:alnum:]]", "", $str1));

 $y=strtolower(ereg_replace("[^[:alnum:]]", "", $str2));

 if ($x==$y) { return(1); } else { return(0); }

}`